# How Absolute changes power rules?

Tags: absolute-value

I have a question about power rules,
we have f(m,n) :

$\ a^{(m-n)}= \frac{a^m}{a^n}$

which is separable. What about:

$\ a^{|m-n|}= ?$

Is it separable? I want f(m,n)=f(n,m)

Thanks.

Comment: What is your initial thoughts? What do you know about absolute values?

Comment: Maybe I should change my question.

Comment: Depends on what $m,n$ are. If they $\in\Bbb R$ (basically any ordered field), you could write it as $\dfrac{a^{\max(m,n)}}{a^{\min(m,n)}}$. For fields like $\Bbb C$ which are not ordered, I don't think any similar simplification exists.

Comment: Also, I think you might want to read over the definition of "commutative"; it's not what you seem to think it is.

Comment: Thank you, my problem is that the min and max are unknown. I want f(m,n)=f(n,m)

Comment: @learner, Thank you.